# how i can check if the path (file) exist or not in unix bash?

Tags: unix, bash, command-line-interface, files

i want to check a path if exist or not before pass it as argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [ -d /tmp ]
then
    echo the directory exists
fi
```

Comment: `i execute if [ -d / $1 ] ; then echo the directory exists else echo the directory not exists fi` .... but always the result is echo the directory not exists ....the command is root@host/>`./bash.sh text.txt `

Comment: you need ";" before "else", additional one before "fi" won't hurt either. You also have a space between "/" and "$1"